# MYSQL Select Join - Specify Unique values on Join

Tags: mysql, select, join, unique

```
SELECT T2.ITEM_ID AS item_ITEM_ID 
FROM types T 
  JOIN items T2
    ON T.ITEM_ID = T2.ITEM_PARENT_ID
WHERE T.ITEM_TYPE = 'I' 
 AND T2.ITEM_TYPE = 'I'
```

This query is returning rows from T2 that have duplicate T2.ITEM_PARENT_IDs. 
How would I specify this query to return only rows that with unique T2.ITEM_PARENT_IDs ?

Answer (score 1):

Count the repeats and filter out when they're more than 1.

```
SELECT T2.ITEM_ID AS item_ITEM_ID, COUNT(*) dups
FROM types T 
  JOIN items T2
    ON T.ITEM_ID = T2.ITEM_PARENT_ID
WHERE T.ITEM_TYPE = 'I' 
 AND T2.ITEM_TYPE = 'I' 
GROUP BY item_ITEM_ID
HAVING dups = 1
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a734/1)